# priceUtils.formatPrice is not a function?

Tags: magento2, price

This is my code which I have in a template:

```
<script>
require(["jquery", 
        "jquery/ui", 
        "mage/translate", 
        "Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils"],function($, priceUtils){ 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        
        $('#qty').on("input", function() {              
            
            var priceForPackages =  priceUtils.formatPrice(somePrice);
                    
        });
        
    })
});
</script>
```

The line `var priceForPackages = priceUtils.formatPrice(somePrice);` gives me the mentioned error. Why is that? Its included and it is not saying the priceUtils is undefined, but the formatPrice function is?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Modify above code a little bit, check the below code

```
require([
    "jquery",
    "jquery/ui",
    "mage/translate",
    "Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils"
], function ($, $ui, trans, priceUtils) {
    'use strict';

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#qty').on("input", function() {

            var priceForPackages =  priceUtils.formatPrice(somePrice);

        });

    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks, when I do this, I get _Mismatched anonymous define() module: function ($, $ui, trans, priceUtils) ..._. I put this code in the template in a <script></script>, like others in the same template.

Comment: I have edited my answer please try again